# rails unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I am generating rails scaffold using default rails scaffold command. But I am getting this error when I am trying to migrate:

```
 syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
  t.float :2011-12
```

To generate scaffold I am using this code:

```
 rails g scaffold Annual_State_Domestic_Product3  Sector:string '2011-12':float '2012-13':float '2013-14':float '2014-15':float '2015-16':float '2016-17':float
```

[Similar answer on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803300/create-migration-for-column-with-a-number-in-the-name) in this Solution is very simple convert this:

```
 t.float :2016-17
```

to something like this:

```
t.float :'2016-17'
```

SO my question is how can I pass value as string from scaffold command as you can see I tried to pass column names as string but nothing happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it

```
rails g migration AnnualStateDomesticProduct3 Sector:string '2011-12':float '2012-13':float '2013-14':float '2014-15':float '2015-16':float '2016-17':float
```

before you run `rake db:migrate`, open your migration file `timestamp_AnnualStateDomesticProduct3` and edit the columns to look like `t.decimal :'2011-12'`

and then run `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Try this please,

```
rails g scaffold Annual_State_Domestic_Product3 Sector:string :'2011-12':float :'2012-13':float :'2013-14':float
```

Etc.,.

Answer (score 0):

Run 
 rails g scaffold Annual_State_Domestic_Product3  Sector:string '2011-12':float '2012-13':float '2013-14':float '2014-15':float '2015-16':float '2016-17':float

After that, Go to migration file and replace
 t.float :2011-12

to

t.float :"2011-12"

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord maps your field name to a ruby variable and you are not allowed to use `-` in a variable name, because it's a math operator so your field name `2011-12` will be interpreted as a math expression like this:

```
2011-12 = 1999
```

Hence the `unexpected tINTEGER` exception.

To avoid this you can use underscore `_` instead of `-` like this `2011_12`:

```
rails g scaffold Annual_State_Domestic_Product3  Sector:string '2011_12':float '2012_13':float '2013_14':float '2014_15':float '2015_16':float '2016_17':float
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you check the similar question on SO that you referred to, in the second answer you would find well explained the issues you would face with your current approach.

To point out one issue, even after your migration succeeds as `t.string "2013-14"` you would not be able call `2013-14` as a method, since ruby doesn't support methods that start with a number.

In order to prevent those issues my suggestion would be to name your attribute `date` or `season` when you're running the migration.